# Easing plugin for anything slider error

Tags: jquery, wordpress, anythingslider

Hey guys for some reason my easing plugin stop working after I switched subdomains. And I'm not seeing anything directly related to paths. "jQuery.easing[jQuery.easing.def] is not a function " is the error that I get. It's working here in my first draft http://dev.mozaiks.com/collections and then loses functionality here http://www.mozaiks.com/collections

Any help would be appreciated thanks!

Comment: Why are you using two different versions of jQuery? Also you seem to be using easing v.1.2 when latest is 1.3.

Comment: No actually that second file that is being loaded I believe is a custom file that is just named arbitrarily something that looks like Jquery. And the only reason I am using easing 1.2 is because I didn't want to run into any issues with compatibility, just wanted to use exactly what was used in the example, but I will look into switching it to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: actually you were right on the money with that @elclanrs I changed to the latest version of Jquery only, but got erros when I jumped to 1.3 of the easing plugin. But put 1.2 back in and it worked, so props to you and thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try uploading your js from your old domain ftp files and make sure your paths are correct. I ran in issue exactly like this. Turns out somehow when I switched my domains between getting and putting files live I loaded an old version of my js.